# Best way to create Singleton Table in Django/MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I want a table which can only have one record.  My current solution is:

```
class HitchingPost(models.Model):
    SINGLETON_CHOICES = (('S', 'Singleton'),)
    singleton = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SINGLETON_CHOICES, unique=True, null=False, default='S');
    value = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"HitchingPost" # only ever one record
```

This is a bit ugly, and doesn't enforce the constraint at the MySQL level.

Is there a better solution?

Is there a MySQL field type which can only have one value (boolean is the smallest I've found, having two possibilities)?  A base-0 digit is the nearest I've come to expressing the concept.

Is there a mathematical name for such a thing?

Thanks,

Chris.

P.S. Generated SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE `appname_hitchingpost` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `singleton` varchar(1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `value` integer NOT NULL
)
;
```

Comment: ''Is there a mathematical name for such a thing?'' - a constant?

Comment: It DOES enforce constraint at MySQL level. Just try e.g. `HitchingPost.objects.create(value=12)` followed by e.g. `HitchingPost.objects.create(value=13)`. If you don't get IntegrityError, then you have some broader problem.

Comment: @Tomasz - yes, it enforces integrity at the Django layer, but the MySQL table has no similar constraints.  A non-Django application could insert value=13 with no problem.  I'll dig out the SQL it creates, if you're interested.

Comment: Django doesn't enforce UNIQUE constraints itself, it's being done by MySQL. So if MySQL doesn't complaint on adding another records manually, then I guess it's because they contain singleton=NULL and for some reason the definition of `singleton` field doesn't contain `NOT NULL` ingridient (have you created that table manually, instead of using `./manage.py syncdb` ?)

Comment: @Tomasz - sorry, my argument was incomplete.  What I should have said is that a non-Django app could insert value=13, provided that it gave a different (i.e. non-'S') value for the singleton field.  Django doesn't create a single-valued MySQL-enum for the singleton field.  I have amended the original question to show the generated SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a bit ugly, and doesn't enforce the constraint at the MySQL level.

If you are worried about enforcement you ought to look at Django's [model validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#validating-objects) methods. You can write a custom `validate_unique` that will raise a `ValidationError` if `HitchingPost.objects.count() != 0`.

```
class HitchingPost(models.Model):
    ...
    def validate_unique(self, exclude = None):
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError, NON_FIELD_ERRORS
        if HitchingPost.objects.count() != 0:
            raise ValidationError({NON_FIELD_ERRORS: ["There can be only one!"]})
```

> Is there a better solution?

Hard to say without getting knowing more about your broader requirement.

> Is there a MySQL field type which can only have one value (boolean is the smallest I've found, having two possibilities)? A base-0 digit is the nearest I've come to expressing the concept.

You can try a custom single element `enum`. I've never tried anything like it, so take my advice with a pinch of salt.

> Is there a mathematical name for such a thing?

`Set-once-constant`? I made that up. In truth I have no idea. Better people here will help you out.

Comment: I just implemented that solution and it worked really well, thanks! Only thing I'd add is so that you can allow the first model to be created and updated, check for the absence of a primary key on the model when saving it as well:
`if not self.pk and HitchingPost.objects.count() > 0:
...`

Comment: if HitchingPost.objects.exclude(id=self.id).count() > 0: allows for updating self.